# Platform.system() gives me 'str objet has no attribute 'system'

Tags: python, python-3.x

whenever I input anything that has to do with the 'clear()' define it instantly breaks and gives me this error.

The issue is coming from the core module of my program and everything on the front end of the program works fine including the 'clear()' function. I've tried moving the 'clear()' function around and rewriting it but nothing works.

```
def clear():
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    os.system('cls')
else:
    os.system('clear')
```

It should clear the terminal but instead I get this error:

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'system'

Comment: You've overwritten `platform` with a string.

Comment: How could I fix it then?

Comment: Make sure platform is something that *does* have a system method?

Comment: it does, if you type print(platform.system()) it outputs either 'Windows' or 'Linux'

Comment: I mean make sure it's *still that* on the line you're complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are overwriting the value of platform somewhere else in your code.
Make sure you are not doing that.

```
import sys
import platform
import os


def clear(system):
    if "Win" in system:
        os.system('cls')
    elif "Lin" in system:
        os.system('clear')

system = platform.system()
print(system)
clear(system)
```

Comment: In my code I still got the same error, it works in other programs and so does my clear() function but just not this one

Comment: Do print(platform) right above system = ... And let me know what the output is

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, I had to replace platform.system with sys.platform and that fixed the problem.

```
import sys
import os


def clear():
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        os.system('cls')
    if sys.platform == 'linux':
        os.system('clear')

print("test")
clear()
```